# Linux: check duplicate from a list of txt

Tags: linux, list, awk, grep, duplicates

What is the best way to remove duplicates from a list of lists?

I have a lot of txt

```
List1.txt   
111  
222  
333  
444  
...
```

```
List300.txt  
555  
666  
777  
888
```

Now I have a new txt List301.txt but need to check duplicate and remove it

```
List301.txt  
111  
666  
999  
aaa  
bbb
```

I was trying to use set like this:

```
cat List* |sort |uniq -u |xargs -i grep {} List* > ListFinal.txt  
List1.txt:222  
List1.txt:333  
List1.txt:444  
List300.txt:555  
List300.txt:777  
List300.txt:888  
List3.txt:999  
List3.txt:aaa  
List3.txt:bbb
```

Have better way to list out `999,aaa,bbb` only or remove `111` and `666` in `List301.txt`?

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

If you have to put the new file (`List301`) in same directory, you can do it with gawk:

```
awk -v fn="f301.txt" 'FILENAME!=fn{a[$0];next}{b[$0]}
    END{for(x in b)if(!(x in a))print x}' *.txt
```

You just change the `fn` value to apply the one-line on your new files.

If you could first move your new file to other directory, say `new/`, you could:

```
awk 'FILENAME!="new/f301.txt"{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' *.txt new/f301.txt
```

Comment: Oh very nice, let me try, Thanks~

Comment: It's great and match, Thanks Kent